# jquery toggle not working properly on table tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to toggle some table rows using jquery. The initial state is hidden

this is working

```
$('.table tr.items.' + name).each(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

and this code is also working

```
$('.table tr.items.' + name).each(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

but with this code

```
$('.table tr.items.' + name).each(function() {
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

In the first call the rows are shown, but in the second call they are not hidden. I can see the style set to style="display: table-row;" in the second call. Do you have an idea on how to solve that?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could edit your question to show your HTML.

Comment: toggling a class is so much better than toggling inline styles when dealing with display.

Comment: Can you please provide snippet?

Comment: @epascarello, millions of devs use jQuery's `show` and `hide` methods like this. You haven't made your case.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: The first two examples are the same? Or am I going mad?

Comment: @isherwood do you want to toggle the display of `td` tag?

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
$('.table tr.items.' + name).toggleClass("notShow");
```

css:

```
.notShow{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: How does this resolve the issue? It's another approach to hiding an element, when the problem is apparently the selector.

Comment: @isherwood HOW would it be the selector when the other two examples work?